# Water distribution - sizing weir buildings

Tags: civil-engineering, hydraulics

I have a building to evenly split a water stream into two: Water flows into central chamber, over two weirs of equal height and length into two chambers and from there into pipelines. I'm looking for rules of the thumb to correctly size the chambers. Weir length is straightforward. But to guarantee even flow over both weirs I need to ensure even flow conditions in the central chamber. So I'm looking on rules of the thumb how wide and high my central chamber has to be, depending on inflow conditions. So far I had no luck with the DWA/ATK (German water and wastewater associaction) guidelines, maybe codes from other countries are helpful here.

Example drawing (top - layout, bottom - cut):
[image]